# Is it possible to use Prismatic schema.core/maybe in a Clojure function precondition?

Tags: clojure, preconditions, plumatic-schema

I'm trying to use [Prismatic `schema.core/maybe`](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) in a precondition for a function taking an optional argument `opts`, but it seems to always throw an `AssertionError` when I call the function with no `opts`:

```
(require '[schema.core :as schema])

(defn foo [& modules]
  {:pre [(schema/validate (schema/maybe [(schema/enum :foo :bar)]) opts)]}
  :yay)

(foo :foo)
;=> :yay

(foo :foo :bar)
;=> :yay

(foo)
;=> AssertionError Assert failed: (schema/validate (schema/maybe [(schema/enum :foo :bar)]) modules)  user/foo (form-init3808809389777994177.clj:1)
```

The interesting thing is that this works as expected:

```
(schema/validate (schema/maybe [(schema/enum :foo :bar)]) nil)
;=> nil
```

I've used `macroexpand` on the `defn`, but nothing looks out of the ordinary there.

I can of course work around this with a precondition like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function precondition must evaluate as truthy for the assertion to pass, but `schema/validate` returns the expression being tested if validation passes, and throws an exception if it fails. You'll need to alter your precondition to always return true if the validation passes:

```
(defn foo [& opts]
  {:pre [(or (schema/validate (schema/maybe [(schema/enum :foo :bar)]) opts) true)]}
  :yay)

(foo :foo) ;=> :yay
(foo :foo :bar) ;=> :yay
(foo) ;=> :yay
(foo :baz) ;=> ExceptionInfo Value does not match schema: [(not (#{:foo :bar} :baz))]
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! I wish schema had a `valid?` function for cases like this. I could roll my own with `(comp nil? schema.core/check)`, I suppose.

Comment: Though come to think of it, if I did that, I would lose Schema's nice error messages, so maybe I'm better off sticking to the `(or (nil? ...))` approach.

Comment: `s/check` is the negation of `valid?`, and more useful -- it returns a descriptive error, or nil if validation passes.  So a better precondition might be `(not (s/check ...))`.